# Typescript - (process.env.PORT - 100 ) Compile time error

Tags: typescript

Getting a compile-time error on *(process.env.PORT - 100)* in the below conditional statement.

```
const port = process.env.PORT ? (process.env.PORT - 100) : 3000;
```

Error says:

> The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interface [ProcessEnv](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/db4d8c51d2028805bfe722c83986f1693d27b9c2/types/node/v12/globals.d.ts#L742) is defined as follows:

```
interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined;
}
```

This means you need to parse this string with `parseInt` to compile cleanly

Answer (score 0):

We need to convert **process.env.PORT** string to number. The corrected code statement is:

```
const port = process.env.PORT ? (+process.env.PORT - 100) : 3000;
```

I'm not using parseInt because **parseInt(null) returns NaN but +null returns 0**

Answer (score 0):

```
let foo = (condition) ? true : false;
const port = process.env.PORT ? (process.env.PORT - 100) : 3000;
```

Just to be clear. If your `$PORT` is `"80"` you want `const port` to be `-20`?

You often see people do this:

```
const port = process.env.PORT | 3000;
```

Or:

```
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT) | 3000;
```